# Designing the sound of a 20" *ahem*... "Member"

Tags: sound-design, microphone, field-recording, sound-effects, foley

So I'm currently posting a rather dark comedic short and well the title beats around the bush but I need to design the movements of a flaccid enormous cock to put it quite bluntly... I have a particular sound in mind already:

I've tried filling up condoms with water and recording the opening but it's not quite there...

Hoping to possibly start a brain hurricane here - any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

bahahahhaha

Ok right, here is what I would do in your situation. Try and put a sausage (a large one i suppose) and put *that* into a condom. Then wet the outside of the condom with water and try hitting it on things. To emulate it being bigger, maybe try and pitch down/timestretch the sound created?

I'd like to know how this turns out jfc

good luck!

-scdave